# Using tramp and ESS-mode, how can I get the R interpreter to execute locally?

Tags: tramp, ess, x11

I use tramp to edit R files on a remote server. When I evaluate R code within ESS-mode, it starts an R interpreter on the remote machine. However, at the moment `ssh -X` to the server does not work, so any R command that produces graphics does not connect to my local X11 server.

Is it possible to configure things so that ESS launches a local R interpreter and, hence, graphics would be displayed locally?

Comment: Just to clarify: you want to do this even though the remote and your local server may have different packages, different versions and different library paths installed?  And saving the graphics as files rather than displaying them immediately is not the desired outcome?

Comment: @gregoryg I've had success using `sshfs` to do this since then the R interpreter executes locally and would like to know if  `tramp` can also do this.

Comment: @gregoryg remote and local are both Linux boxes, albeit different distributions.

Comment: `sshfs` and TRAMP take opposite approaches.  `sshfs` makes remote files appear local with a mount, allowing all processing to be local.  TRAMP sends all processing to the remote machine, where files are dealt with as local only.  So I don't think you can solve your use case with TRAMP.  If you do want to save the remote graphics as files without invoking a viewer, you will be able to view those files in Emacs.   But that's a different workflow.

Comment: @gregoryg Please upgrade the comment to a solution and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that TRAMP can work well in this use case.  You mention `sshfs` in a comment, but the two work differently.

`sshfs` and TRAMP take opposite approaches. `sshfs` makes remote files appear local with a mount, allowing all processing to be local. TRAMP sends all processing to the remote machine, where files are dealt with as local only.

So I don't think you can solve your use case with TRAMP. If you do want to save the remote graphics as files without invoking a viewer, you will be able to view those files in Emacs. But that's a different workflow.

Answer (score 2):

I've fixed my `ssh -X` problem. Using `tramp`, in the remote R interpreter launched by `ESS`

```
> View(tibble)
```

with a 3,722-row tibble is not responsive with my 200 Mbps download speed. But using `sshfs` the same R interpreter is local and, hence, the `View` graphic is just as responsive as if I were sitting at the console of the remote machine. For me, this is the best workflow for creating R scripts at the remote machine. Thanks to gregoryg for comparing tramp/sshfs workflows and explaining that launching a local R process with `tramp` is not possible.

Comment: Can you please point to documentation on how to achieve  this, or share your own?